# Efficient way to store random set of x, y screen variables to a list in Python

Tags: python

I want this code to draw x number of stars on the screen and then have the stars occasionally blink. Before I figure out how to make stars blink, I'm trying to first figure out how to store the randomly-generated x, y coordinates. To a list or list of lists?

Here's my code so far. It works as far as it goes. Notice I have two different size stars. But that just makes it more interesting!

```
import pygame
from random import randint
pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("My God, it's full of stars!")

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
gray = (50,50,50)

x = randint(1,800)
y = randint(1,600)
p = randint(1,800)
q = randint(1,600)
r = randint(1,800)
s = randint(1,600)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
crashed = False
med_star_img = pygame.image.load('images/medium_star.png')
tiny_star_img = pygame.image.load('images/tiny_star.png')

def make_star(x,y):
        gameDisplay.blit(med_star_img, (x,y))
        gameDisplay.blit(tiny_star_img, (p,q))
        gameDisplay.blit(tiny_star_img, (r,s))
        
while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

    gameDisplay.fill(gray)
    make_star(x,y)
    pygame.display.flip()
    # pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Edit:
I'm not sure what to do in the make_star function. Here is the revised code.

```
import pygame
from random import randint
pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

# screen color choices
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
gray = (50,50,50)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("My God, it's full of stars!")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
crashed = False
med_star_img = pygame.image.load('images/medium_star.png')
tiny_star_img = pygame.image.load('images/tiny_star.png')

stars_location = []
stars_width = 0
stars_height = 0

#what this for loop does is that it runs the amount of times the range is
#for example if the range is 3
#and i print('hi') inside this loop
#it will print hi 3 times

for i in range(5):
    #what append does is it adds whatever you put in the brackets to the list      
    stars_location.append(pygame.Rect(randint(1,800),randint(1,600),stars_width,stars_height))

print(stars_location)


# Draw star
def make_star(x,y):
        gameDisplay.blit(med_star_img,(x,y))

        
while not crashed:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        crashed = True
        for star in stars_location:
                make_star(star.x,star.y)

        gameDisplay.fill(gray)
        pygame.display.flip()
        # pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: You can try in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is outside of the while loop create a for loop that has a range of the amount of stars you want to draw:

```
stars_location = []

#what this for loop does is that it runs the amount of times the range is
#for example if the range is 3
#and i print('hi') inside this loop
#it will print hi 3 times

for i in range(amount of stars):
    #what append does is it adds whatever you put in the brackets to the list      
    stars_location.append(pygame.Rect(randint(1,800),randint(1,600),stars_width,stars_height))
```

what this code does is that it adds the x and y value in the list, `pygame.Rect()` stores the x,y and width, height of the specified values, so you can easily access them for example if i set a variable `tree = pygame.Rect(100,50,75,75)` and i say to the program `print(tree.x)` it will print 100 and if i say `print(tree.width)` it will print the width (you get the point) so you can say later on:

Make sure this code is in the while loop:

```
for star in stars_location:
   make_star(star.x,star.y)
```

what this does is that it goes through the list `stars_location` and takes every value of it, so if the list is `[pygame.Rect(100,50,75,75),pygame.Rect(200,75,25,25)]` and you print star, it will give you `(100,50,75,75) and (200,75,25,25)`

Comment: I'm not sure what to do in make_stars function. See revised code in my post above.

Comment: what do you mean by you dont know what to do with make_stars, just keep it the same everything should work.

Comment: I get a NameError: name 'stars_width' is not defined. So then I add the following:

stars_width = 0
stars_height = 0

And then the code runs but nothing happens. Just a blank gray screen. I tried printing stars_location and get the following:

[<rect(327, 494, 0, 0)>, <rect(195, 357, 0, 0)>, <rect(552, 29, 0, 0)>, <rect(631, 228, 0, 0)>, <rect(211, 227, 0, 0)>]

Comment: oh, what i mean by star_width and star_height is that YOU have to say the width and the height of the object, and why did u put it 0, what i mean by width and height is the SIZE od the object, go to ur image properties and you will see something like 50x50, the first number being width and the second height.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. It works! Though in the previous iteration of this code, I didn't bother with width and height and yet it still drew the stars to the screen.

Comment: I ended up using image.get_width() and image.get_height() to set these variables. Thanks much!

Comment: no worries, haha i forgot the image.get_width and height existed.